# Difference between "今日の会話これ意味わかりました？" and "今日の会話の意味わかりました？""

Tags: meaning, nuances, particle-の

Would someone be so nice as to explain to me the fine nuances and subtleties between the two sentences:

1. 今日の会話 これ 意味わかりました？ (Source: [Lower intermediate season 4, lesson 1](https://www.japanesepod101.com/lesson/lower-intermediate-lesson-s4-1-giving-and-receiving-in-japanese-introduction/?lp=137))
2. 今日の会話   の 意味わかりました？   (Source: Myself)

Comment: Isn't これ意味 just wrong?

Comment: A native Japanese female speaker spoke it in a podcast, of which I included the link in an edit of my post, under which you can find the transcript of the podcast. You can find it under "Post conversation banter".

Answer (score 4):

I haven't listened to the podcast but from the script

> Naomi: 　ピーターさん、今日の会話これ意味わかりました？**ダイアログの中に下駄箱を開けると、手紙が落ちる。**
>
> Peter: So I think I understand. In the dialog script it says, he opens the door to his shoe box, and out falls a letter. But shoe box is really shoe box as in ???(00: 07: 22) the English speaker would know it. Such as a box ???(00: 07: 25). It’s more like a little locker that you put your shoes in.

今日の会話これ意味わかりました? means 今日の会話の中**で/の**これ**の**意味わかりました?=*In today's conversation, did you see the meaning of this?*

これ refers specifically to the bold part in the above quote.  Naomi asks this because shoeboxes as found in Japan (with doors) is not common abroad.

今日の会話(の)意味わかりました? would mean *Did you understand the whole conversation of today?*

Comment: Should ダイアログの中に also be put in bold, or only 下駄箱を開けると、手紙が落ちる?

Comment: @aguijonazo Not sure. But it seems the scene *is* in the dialogue (inside the dialogue), so bolding it may not be completely wrong.

Comment: OK. It’s just a question of whether to read it as ダイアログの中に（出てきた）「下駄箱を開けると、手紙が落ちる」（という表現） or ダイアログの中に「下駄箱を開けると、手紙が落ちる」（という表現が出てきたこと）. I somehow read it in the first way. The second has less gap to fill indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can all agree that those sentences are just omitting particles. In my mother language it's a very a common thing to not say the grammatical words especially when speaking casually and fast simply because when you start to speak, the sentence is not all made in your head yet and instead of saying the rest in a wrong way because it won't fit, you just say the words scattered. It seems to be the case.